# Use glossary term in another entry

Tags: errors, compiling, glossaries, xindy

It may be useful to me to reference a glossary entry in another, as in

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, brazil]{book}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \makeglossaries
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Using_defined_terms
\usepackage[xindy,toc]{glossaries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\printglossary[type=main,style=altlist]

\newglossaryentry{firstterm}{
    name={some first term},
    description={first term description in here},
    first={first version of first term},
    long={long version of first term},
    plural={plural version of first term},
    firstplural={first plural version of first term}
}

\newglossaryentry{secondterm}{
    name={some second term},
    description={second term description in here,
        which could use \gls{firstterm}},
    first={first version of second term},
    long={long version of second term},
    plural={plural version of second term},
    firstplural={first plural version of second term}
}

Then here is the text, where I can refer to my terms
normally, either by \gls{firstterm}, \gls{secondterm},
\gls*{firstterm} or \gls*{secondterm}.

\end{document}
```

The main point here is when I (wish I could) do

```
\newglossaryentry{secondterm}{
    (...)
    description={\gls{firstterm}**},
    (...)
}
```

without the error

```
./main.gls:<someline>: Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `firstterm' has not been defined. [\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{8}}}]
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You're trying to use the term within `\printglossary` but you don't define the term until later. Try moving all your `\newglossaryentry` commands to the preamble (or at the very least before `\printglossary`).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terms must be defined before they are used, and since they are used in the glossary, you need to move the definitions before `\printglossary`. Like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, brazil]{book}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[xindy,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{firstterm}{
    name={some first term},
    description={first term description in here},
    first={first version of first term},
    long={long version of first term},
    plural={plural version of first term},
    firstplural={first plural version of first term}
}

\newglossaryentry{secondterm}{
    name={some second term},
    description={second term description in here,
        which could use \gls{firstterm}},
    first={first version of second term},
    long={long version of second term},
    plural={plural version of second term},
    firstplural={first plural version of second term}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\printglossary[type=main,style=altlist]

Then here is the text, where I can refer to my terms
normally, either by \gls{firstterm}, \gls{secondterm},
\gls*{firstterm} or \gls*{secondterm}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just did great! I exported the entries to an external file and used with `\loadglsentries{glossary.tex}` in the preamble, and worked!